# Configure only an ip address for an isolated eth0 attached to an ip cam

Tags: networking, netplan

I have ubuntu 20.04 server on a raspberry pi 4B.  It is connected to my lan via wlan0, no problem, using netplan.
It is monitoring some BLE devices.
Now I want to connect an IP cam to my ethernet port. I want
eth0 to have ip address 192.168.3.1. In the old days I would simply run  ifconfig eth0 192.168.3.1 up in rc.local and
also set up a cron job to make sure eth0 had not been dropped.

I would like to do this with netplan instead as part of learning this new system.  Everything I find seems to screw up the routing. I want to leave everything alone except to assign the desired ip address to eth0. I know this should be trivial
unless it is impossible. any help appreciated.

Comment: Explore https://netplan.io/ .

Comment: Wouldn't the IP cam require DHCP?

Comment: no. it has a static ip address 192.168.3.45

Comment: Could you please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1389045/edit) your question with the contents of the Netplan file you tried?  You can also still install `ifconfig` and get the system working with the old way by installing both `net-tools` and `ifupdown` but if you are going to go with those you would have to remove or disable Netplan.

Comment: I assume you don't have Network Manager GUI on your system? Because with GUI it's trivial.

Comment: Actually I just wanted to know if there was a simple way to do it with netplan.  I know about the workarounds.  In the meantime I added a system D service which just runs a script to use ifconfig and also added a cron job to check if the interface has been dropped and assign the ip address to it again.  BTW I am an old Linux user.  Remember soft landing software?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The netplan equivalent of `ifconfig eth0 192.168.3.1 up` is:

```
network:
  renderer: networkd
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      addresses: [ "192.168.3.1/24" ]
```

Comment: OK, thanks for that. It appear to work perfectly.